# NSNotification not handled by subview contained in a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter

In my AppDelegate, I'm instantiating a UINavigationController and adding my "main" view (let's call it *MainViewController*) as the root view controller for the navigation controller.  The navigation controller is then added as a subview to the app delegate's window and the window is made visible.  I.e.,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // viewController is a property of the app delegate
   viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
   viewController.context = [self managedObjectContext];

   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

   [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

*MainViewController* adds observers for some NSNotifications that are posted by a subview of a view controller programmatically instantiated and added as a subview of *MainViewController*.  So,

- *MainViewController* (in UINavigationController)

  - *SubViewController*

    - *SubView* that posts notifications

Once I added the UINavigationController to the mix, *MainViewController* no longer properly handles the notification posted by *SubView*.  If I remove the UINavigationController and simply add *MainViewController* as a subview of the AppDelegate's window, the notifications are handled properly.

I tried adding an observer to the AppDelegate for one of the notifications posted by *SubView* and it handles it properly, and while handling that notification, the *MainViewController* is not nil.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you'd like any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a couple of things were happening here:

1. `viewController` was not actually a property on my app delegate.  Making it a property caused the NSNotification to be handled again.
2. After that was sorted out, the code in the selector being triggered by the NSNotification wasn't working properly--it was supposed to push a new view into *MainViewController*'s navigationController, which was nil.  Creating a property in the app delegate for the UINavigationController fixed this issue, too.

Comment: Having the navController reference at app delegate is a good thing. However you must be able to access the navController instance via view controller's `navigationController` property rather than asking the app delegate for it (it could be different navControllers if you accidentally change the app delegate property, while the `navigationController` property of any view controller is filled automatically for you), that is valid both for the root and pushed view controllers.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip.  I've been making sure to use self.navigationController whenever pushing a new view onto the stack, so that hasn't bitten me yet.